# How to offset text in D3 node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, force-layout

I am trying to use the D3 javascript library to make a force-directed graph, and I want to offset text appended to my nodes.  However, no attributes that I seem to try and change have an affect on this.  Instead, my text gets overlayed on the node and it's very hard to read:

[image]

Here is how I am appending the text:

```
  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", -3)
      .attr("text-anchor", "right")
      .style("color", "white", null)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

I have tried different values of *dx* and *dy* but nothing seems to offset the text.  It always looks the same.

---

Edit: Full code (http://g.nychis.com/force-directed.zip and open force-edges-names.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Force-Directed Layout</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v2.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

div.node {
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  position: absolute;
}

div.link {
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: solid #999 1px;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#000000">
  <FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">Floor: 1</FONT>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var width = 700,
    height = 500,
    radius = 6,
    fill = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(-100)
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return (d.value-d.sub)*8; })
    .size([width, height]);

var vis = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .style("width", width + "px")
    .style("height", height + "px");

d3.json("home.json", function(json) {
  var link = vis.selectAll("div.link")
      .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("div")
      .attr("class", "link");

  var node = vis.selectAll("div.node")
      .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("div")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("background", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })
      .style("border-color", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.group)).darker(); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("text")
        .style("color", "white", null)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force
      .nodes(json.nodes)
      .links(json.links)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

  function tick() {
    node.style("left", function(d) { return (d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x))) + "px"; })
        .style("top", function(d) { return (d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y))) + "px"; });

    link.style("left", function(d) { return d.source.x + "px"; })
        .style("top", function(d) { return d.source.y + "px"; })
        .style("width", length)
        .style("-webkit-transform", transform)
        .style("-moz-transform", transform)
        .style("-ms-transform", transform)
        .style("-o-transform", transform)
        .style("transform", transform);
  }

  function transform(d) {
    return "rotate(" + Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x) * 180 / Math.PI + "deg)";
  }

  function length(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) + "px";
  }
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of element is node?

Comment: SVG's text-anchor style can have the value start, middle and end; it's different from HTML's text-align property, which uses left, center and right.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the text element:

```
node.append("div")
    .style("transform", "translate(0px,-10px)")
    ...
    .html(...);
```

The name of the "transform" property depends on the browser you're using, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp). You might want to set all of these.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to do anything, either

Comment: Ah, I assumed that you were generating an SVG. Updated.

Comment: still doesn't do anything :\

Comment: Just realised that there are no "text" elements in HTML. Should work with a "div" though.

Comment: still no luck with the div either... here is a zip of the code: http://g.nychis.com/force-directed.zip ... just open force-edges-names.html and you'll see the translate doesn't shift it

Comment: Whether this works actually depends on the browser you're using :) I've updated the answer.

Comment: I see... I'm using chrome but even trying to use the webkit form I can't get it to work.

Comment: Works fine for me (with Chrome and "-webkit-transform").

Comment: would you be willing to pastebin me a new set of code that actually does the shift? I still can't get it to work

Comment: All I did was change "transform" to "-webkit-transform" in your code.

Comment: sigh, i swear it is still not working for me.  Take a look at: http://g.nychis.com/force/force-edges-names-test.html ... it has the exact code you're suggesting and I see no offset in the names.  I've opened it in chrome and safari which use that same transform tag (view the page source)

Comment: You need to change the "text" element into a "div".

Answer (score 0):

```
node.append("text")
  .attr({
    "dy": -3,
    "transform": "translate(" + 15 + "," + 5 + ")"
  })
  .style("color", "white", null)
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```